# BigQuery API limit on DELETE DML with WHERE clause

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BQ table with ~60k rows. A portion of these rows have a field called 'Temporary' that takes a Boolean value. Every morning, I send a query to BQ via the Python `pandas_gbq` [package](https://pandas-gbq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reading.html). The query is simple: `DELETE FROM table WHERE Temporary = 'True'`. However, lately I have been getting a `400` error from the API: `400 GET ... API limit exceeded: Unable to return a row that exceeds the API limits. To retrieve the row, export the table.` I'm not sure how any 'row' exceeds the API limit since this should only delete some rows, not return any. Is there a better way to programmatically delete portions of data from a BQ table?

Comment: the error message looks like returned when you fetch data from a table. Could you double confirm if the error message is from the very `DELETE` query, or is it possible that you have some logic to fetch table data after deletion and the error was popped up there?

Comment: @YunZhang I'm checking this out. I checked the query log in the console and I'm even more confused because the query that seems to be throwing the error is marked as 'completed' in the log. But, no other queries are shown to be attempted after it.

Comment: seems like a bug - please use the BigQuery issue tracker and make sure to include job ids